# Lubuntu 12.04 change screen brightness. Lenovo ThinkPad

Tags: lubuntu, screen, brightness

How do I change the screen brightness in Lubuntu 12.04?

The screen brightness is stuck in a very bright mode and it's quite uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the shortcuts fn-f8 and fn-f9 change screen brithtness on lenovo thinkpad with lubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at your system settings -> power settings.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/screenshotfrom201302081.png/

I dont know if you have the same settings though, since mine is mint 14...

Comment: Yes iǘe been going through the power settings. I can set it so that the brightness changes after so an so much time inactive etc. But no way to actually just set the brightness.